# Android Mediaplayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

i want to play an audio on my android app using the Mediaplayer class. 
my problem is on the R.java part.
to better understand my problem, i'll have to show a part of my code

```
audioControl = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.forward_100hz);
        audioControl.start();
```

so, the problem is on the forward_100hz, which is my wav file which is stated that it cannot be resolved or it is not a field. 
how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with your imports. Probably you've already imported the android.R class, but not the R class of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the file is stored in the folder **res/raw**
Try deleting the R file generated by eclipse if the file is in place

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the file forward_100hz is in res/raw folder
2. Check your imports and remove import android.R;
3. If on Eclipse press Ctrl + Shift + O to auto suggest import and you should import

> import your.package.name.R;
>
> If 3 does not work check your manifest file and then res directory for error which might be causing the problem by not generating R.java

Answer (score 0):

As the second parameter of the `create` method put the following `path`:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://<package-name>/"+ R.raw.forward_100hz);
```

Answer (score -1):

First sure that folder/raw exists and create the Mediaplayer before of on create

```
MediaPlayer player;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    player=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.forward_100hz);
    player.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the is described as the erroneous case in the question?

Comment: then what is it?